# Whats the difference between the Remote Desktop Services options on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, roles

Whats the difference between the early option when installing Remote Desktop Services compared to explicitly choosing Remote Desktop Services under the Roles section? (All within the Add Roles and Features wizard).

Hope this is clear.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "early option", but more than likely there is no difference.  What makes you think there *is* a difference?  What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: When you open the Add Roles and Features wizard, you get the option to go on and Add Roles.., or to install Remote Desktop. I'm curious because you do go through a different procedure when installing it, compared to explicitly choosing it under Roles. It seems that the "early option" has a more detailed installation compared to the explicit option...Tho I could be wrong

Comment: I did go ahead and used the explicit option under Roles because the process was easier. Again I'm only curious about the "early option" because it may have an advantageous benefit for remotely accessing the server with a domain account. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the "early option" walks you through the process; standard or Quick start, VM-based or Session-based, deploying a Session Broker, etc. and reduces the number of items and options that you need to manually select.

Whereas doing it later requires you to manually add those Role components and make those choices.

If you're new to RDS in Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 and just want to get it off the ground then the "early option" is the easiest way to get RDS deployed. If you're familiar with RDS in Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 then you may want to take a more manual, controlled approach and not use the "early option".

Note that the "early option" is always available to you from the `Add Roles and Features` wizard in Server Manager. You just need select the `Remote Desktop Services installation` option.